# 'str' does not support the buffer interface while uploading and submitting csv file in Django

Tags: python, django, csv

I want to upload a csv file and store it in a database. My Django version is 1.9 and Python3.4. Below is the code. My app name is 'pft'
pft/utils.py

```
from .models import Account
import csv
def handle_uploaded_file(file, valid_fields_method, record_creation_function):
    file.seek(0)
    # !importtant
    # csv file must be encoded in UTF-8
    sniffdialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(file.read(10000), delimiters='\t,;')
    file.seek(0)
    #print sniffdialect.fieldnames
    data = csv.DictReader(file, dialect=sniffdialect)
    if not valid_fields_method(data.fieldnames):
        return False, -1
    result, rows_error = record_creation_function(data)
    return result, rows_error
def account_valid_fields(field_names):
    required_fields = ('species', 'x', 'y')
    for field in required_fields:
        if field not in field_names:
            return False
    return False
def create_account_in_db(dict_data):
    list_data = []
    result = False
    rows_error = 0
    for record in dict_data:
        species = record['species']
        x = record['x']
        y = record['y']
        account = models.Account(species=species,\
                                 x=x,\
                                 y=y)
        list_data.append(account)
    if list_data:
       # bulk_create will create multiple object in a single query
        created_accounts = models.Account.objects.bulk_create(list_data)
        if len(list_data) == len(created_accounts):
            result=True
        else:
            rows_error = len(list_data) - len(created_accounts)
    return result, rows_error
```

models.py

```
class Account(models.Model):
    species=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    x=models.IntegerField()
    y=models.IntegerField()

    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    first_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s %s" % (self.species, self.x,self.y)
```

views.py

```
def add_multiple_accounts(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        csv_upload_form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if csv_upload_form.is_valid():
             file = csv_upload_form.cleaned_data['file']
             csv_result, rows_error = utils.handle_uploaded_file(file, utils.account_valid_fields, utils.create_account_in_db)
             if csv_result:
                 message = 'Successfully imported accounts from the csv file to the database.\n'
                 message += 'The system is creating Active Directory Accounts using those information in the background.\n'
                 message += 'Please wait...'
                 messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, message)
             else:
                 message = 'There are some errors occured. Please try again.'
                 messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, message)
        else:
                 csv_upload_form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('add_multiple.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^csv',add_multiple_accounts),
```

add.mutilple.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ csv_upload_form.as_p }}
   <button type="submit" class="action green btn-center" name="action" value="add_csv"><span class="label">Upload</span></button>
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When I click the submit button I get the above error. How can I solve this?

Comment: in which line is this happenning?

Comment: In C:\Python34\lib\csv.py in _guess_delimiter, line 300   i.e data = list(filter(None, data.split('\n'))). Also I have changed the line matches = regexp.findall(data)    to  matches = regexp.findall(data.decode('utf-8'))

Comment: just paste the whole traceback please

Comment: the complete error is http://dpaste.com/3JCW29Y

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
file_content = bytes(file.read(10000), 'UTF-8')
sniffdialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(file_content, delimiters='\t,;')
```

it is because `string` in Python3.x is not the same as in python2.x, you need to cast it with bytes and encode as utf-8

Comment: When I add the above code I'm getting the following error File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\geodjango\pft\utils.py" in handle_uploaded_file
  8.     file_content = bytes(file.read(10000), 'UTF-8')

Exception Type: TypeError at /csv
Exception Value: encoding or errors without a string argument